# error installing a package in R pertaining stringr package

Tags: linux, r, package, linux-mint

I have problem with installing packages in RStudio.
I'm using Linux Mint and have already installed libgdal-dev and libproj-dev.

Here's the text in the terminal:

```
* installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for local ICUDT_DIR... icu55/data
checking for R_HOME... /usr/lib/R
checking for R... /usr/lib/R/bin/R
checking for R >= 3.1.0... no
*** disabling C++11 use
checking for cat... /bin/cat
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... g++ -E
configure: error: in `/tmp/Rtmp3NFJZN/R.INSTALL28c32774afde/stringi':
configure: error: C preprocessor "g++ -E" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
* removing ‘/home/varum/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/stringi’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpv9QKWM/downloaded_packages’
```

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: There should be more details in the `config.log`.

Comment: There is a number of questions with similar or same error message. Please indicate which, if any at all, have you read to see if their solution (if available) solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> checking for R >= 3.1.0... no

It might help to update your R version. The current release is version 3.2.2

Check the installation guidelines [here](https://cran.r-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe installing the g++ could help

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped!